# Can we mount s3 bucket which already has some files and directories in it using S3FS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, object-storage, s3fs

**Am trying to mount S3 bucket with some data to an EC2 instance. Am not getting any error, but df -h is not showing it as mounted.**

**Can you suggest any other better open source software for the same operation. I want to mount S3 bucket with lots of data locally and perform operations on it.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

while mounting add -f option it displays the error, without this option s3fs does not show any error. Here I had added wrong credentials inside passwd-s3fs file! Hope Its gonna help someone someday :)

Also for more better performance try goofys or riofs (opensource) and objectiveFS(paid) for mounting s3 bucket.